# What beans does the DispatcherServlet instantiate on startup?

Tags: servlets, spring-mvc

- What beans are instantiated by the DispatcherServlet when the server starts?
- How can I observe those instantiations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the container starts your `DispatcherServlet`, it will then in turn instantiate every bean defined in the application context, unless that bean has been defined as `lazy-init`.

As to when your container starts the `DispatcherServlet`, that depends if the servlet has `<load-on-startup>` defined in the `web.xml` file.